# Escaping a SQLite query in a bash script

Tags: sql, bash, sqlite, escaping, quotes

In a bash script I have

```
my_query="\'select uid from lastlog;\'"
```

If I then write

```
sqlite test.db ${my_query}
```

I get the error

```
/usr/bin/sqlite3: Error: too many options: "uid"
```

What is the correct way to escape the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Taking your example and `echo` it clearly shows the issue.

```
$ my_query="\'select uid from lastlog;\'"
$ echo $my_query
\'select uid from lastlog;\'
```

As your variable is already quoted, there is no need to escape the nested single quotes.

```
$ my_query="'select uid from lastlog;'"
$ echo $my_query
'select uid from lastlog;'
```

Comment: You are right about not needing to escape the nested quotes, but I still need some quotes for the call to sqlite to ensure that the whole query is interpreted as a single argument. This is shown in my own answer to the question (but which is in fact someone else's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Someone wrote the following answer:

```
my_query='select uid from lastlog;'
sqlite test.db "${my_query}"
```

but then deleted it almost immediately, but luckily I saw it and it works for me.

Comment: You may find this tool helpful when you're writing shell scripts: https://www.shellcheck.net/